# Expected energy in micro-canonical and canonical distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

Which relation $E(β)$ is required to ensure that he micro-canonical distribution and the canonical
distribution have the same expected energy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between energy and temperature (or its inverse $\beta$) is highly system-dependent. The energy $E$, in the microcanonical ensemble, is a fixed external parameter, while $\beta_{micro}$ is $\frac{\partial{S_{micro}}}{\partial{E}}$, within a constant factor (the inverse Boltzmann constant). In the canonical ensemble, $\beta_{can}$ is an independent fixed parameter, while the average internal energy can be obtained as
$$
U_{can} = \frac{\partial{(\beta_{can} F_{can})}}{\partial{\beta_{can}}},
$$
$F_{can} = U_{can} - T_{can}S_{can}$ being the Helmholtz free energy.

The possibility that
$$
\beta_{can} = \beta_{micro}   \iff U_{can} = E
$$
is the so-called equivalence of the ensemble.

It holds under quite general conditions on the hamiltonian (existence of the [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit)) as an asymptotic result in the limit of large systems. It does not depend on a specific $E(\beta)$ relation.